# Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between System.DateTime and null

Tags: c#, expression

```
DateTime tempDate = calculatesomedatetime();
someDateTimeControl.Value = null; //no issue
someDateTimeControl.Value = (tempDate > DateTime.MinValue)? tempDate : null;
```

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between System.DateTime and null

Line 3 throwing me such error which I don't understand as the comparison is `(tempDate > DateTime.MinValue)` and `null` is just value assignment. Why would compiler interpret this as error?

However if I write as below, it has no problem

```
if(tempDate > DateTime.MinValue)
{
    someDateTimeControl.Value = tempDate;
}else
{
    someDateTimeControl.Value = null;
}
```

Comment: `DateTime` is a `struct`. It cannot be assigned to `null`. You need to either declare it as `nullable` (like: `DateTime? tempDate = ...`) or use some other default value, like `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: @RufusL: Please refer to my line2, the control can accept null

Comment: Oh, I must have misread it initially, but the issue is still basically the same. The ternary operator infers the type being returned by the first part, which is a `DateTime`. You still need to either define `tempDate` as nullable, or cast it to nullable in the ternary expression.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The issue is with the ternary operation. You're changing the data type from DateTime to a nullable DateTime. Ternary operations require you to return the same data type both before and after the colon. Doing something like this would work:

```
someDateTimeControl.Value = (tempDate > DateTime.MinValue) ? (DateTime?)tempDate : null;
```

Answer (score 4):

Cast both sides to a nullable DateTime, that way it is returning the same type on both sides.

```
someDateTimeControl.Value = (tempDate > DateTime.MinValue)? (DateTime?)tempDate : (DateTime?)null;
```